# Cakephp 3.X Auth Component Signin with multiple fields

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to make user login with two fields i.e. username and email. Check if username or email is matching and verify password. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use The MultiColumn authenticate adaptor from this plugin:

https://github.com/friendsofcake/authenticate#multicolumnauthenticate